# Lock table on postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.6

i'm new in postgres administration and when developper run `LOCK TABLE tab1;` with `PREPARED`statement , postgres use `ACCES EXCLUSIVE` BY DEFAULT. My probelem is that the lock in table is still here after one week in view `pg_prepared_xact` and `pg_locks` even after restart of postgres and in pg_lock is like:

```
 vXID                 mode
-1/192836             AccessExclusiveLock
```

```
Name               DATABASE                  Owner             XID          prepared at
                   db1                       postgres          192836       20-07-2021
```

I would know why the LOCK is still here?? and how to solve it? and what is mean -1 in vXID?? because i can't even show my data on `tab1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with PREPARED statement

Prepared transactions and prepared statements are very different things.  What you have here is a prepared transaction.  Surviving a restart is what prepared transactions are *for*.  You need to find its "gid" in pg_prepared_xacts and then either manually commit it or [roll it back](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-rollback-prepared.html).  If you are not intentionally using prepared transactions, the you should set max_prepared_transactions =0, so this can't recur.  If you are intentionally using them, you need to learn how to handle them.

Comment: yes it works!! I use `ROLLBACK PREPARED` to fix it. I didn't  use prepared, the developper did, and yes he uses the PREPARED TRANSACTION.

Comment: I would know the meaning of -1 in xVID?